# ftp link without password for my websiteusers

Tags: html, web, hyperlink, ftp, server

On my website I want to put a href="" link.

I want that when the user clicks on a hyperlink it opens a new Tab with a pdf.

This pdf is on my ftp server in a file.

But i don't know which link i have to put on href="".

I've tested with this example: ftp://username:password@servername.com the example works, but the second problem is, I don't want that the users see my password in the link.

I work usually with html and I don't know very much about ftp server hosting etc.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `http://` protocol to view files regularly. For practical purposes, anybody can view a webpage over `http://`. `ftp://` is used to edit the server's files, thus needing a password to protect it. This is used for server access/maintenance purposes, and is not intended to actually serve data to the public.

Therefore it is necessary to use `http://`, and obviating the need for a username/password.

The URL should be changed to `http://yourdomain.com/directory/to/pdf.pdf`.

Comment: but the second problem exists again. the webuser can see on the link my usename and password. how can i hidden just the password.

Comment: @LucaArchidiacono Sorry. I made a copy and paste mistake, and I came back to fix it now.

Comment: @bcdan why is it that this isn't working for me? If my url is ftp://username%2540website.com@website.com/Folder1/Folder2/Audiofile.mp3 then what do I need to change to make it work? When I substitute the beginning for http://website.com/... it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter about username and password credentials, you can just generate a link to the pdf on the server and link to it from the website, by:

1. create a 'documents' folder on the server in the root
2. add the pdf from your computer, to this documents folder, using your ftp client
3. using your ftp client, inside the documents folder, right-click on the document >> ‘file-name.pdf’ >>  File Custom Commands >> Generate HTTP URL >> copy
4. paste this into your code as the href="copiedGeneratedHttpUrl"
5. rebuild and deploy.

I'm building in React and my ftp client is WinSCP. This works for me.